# flutter Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/room/room-common/maven-metadata.xml

Tags: flutter, dart

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve androidx.room:room-common:[2.2.5].
> Required by:
> project :app > project :workmanager > androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0 > androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5
> > Failed to list versions for androidx.room:room-common.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/room/room-common/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/room/room-common/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/room/room-common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: search jCenter is used in your project anywhere. If yes then replace jCenter by Maven.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be your project level build.gradle file using this : `maven { url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/' }`   it should be replaced by `maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'}`